# Angular how can i get the input value of appended element

Tags: html, angularjs

I have here my code of html basically its an color picker and a textbox when user pick a color i'm appending the value to the color hex texfield and user can add multiple colors i'm appending those two inputs when user click on add more it will add another set of two inputs but how do i get the colors that the user add and maybe push it to an array? Please help i would really appreciate it. Thankyou!

```
    <div class="add_items_color_container" id="colors">
      <input type="text" readonly data-wheelcolorpicker="" data-wcp-preview="true" data-wcp-format="css" class="color">
      <input type="text" class="color_hex">
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using jquery version of Color picker, 
in angular, you can read using queryselector,element.value , but its not recommended in angular,

you can use the angular version from https://github.com/patlux/ng-colorwheel